# Excel--Show X-Value of Data when Y-Value is a Maximum

Tags: excel, vba, max

I have multiple Excel spreadsheets with two columns of data (x-coordinates in Column A and y-coordinates in Column B). In another cell, F4, I have the maximum value of Column B. However, I do not know which cell this maximum value is found in. In cell F3, I want the CORRESPONDING x-value to be written.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I am unaware of this method at the moment.

I will take any and all suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a):

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F4,B:B,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're in the home button, on the top left you'll find a button called 'filter'.
Highlight column B, click the filter button, then filter from greatest to least.
The greatest value in column B should be at the top.